# Regular expression to find meta robots noindex tag

Tags: regex, preg-match, meta, noindex

I have to check wether a page has a robots noindex meta tag in its source code and I want to catch as many different html syntax variants as possible.

First i tried get_meta_tags() function, but it has some limitations, so I decided to stick with preg_match.

I tried this regular expression:

```
"/<meta\s+name\s*=\s*[\"'](.*?)[\"']\s*content\s*=\s*[\"'].*?noindex.*?[\"']\s*\/?>/i"
```

however it fails when the noindex meta tag is like this (content part first):

```
<meta content="follow, index"  name="robots" />
```

Can anyone share a more appropriate regular expression to achieve my goal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

method without long/big preg's:

```
    if (preg_match_all('/\<meta.*?\>/mis',$s,$m) and strstr(join(',',$m[0]),'noindex')){

        echo 'page contains noindex meta tag';

    }else{

        echo 'without noindex meta tag';
    }
```